# Is it possible to assign a lua function from Sol3 to a c++ function pointer or std::function

Tags: c++, lua

I would like to assign lua functions to C++ function pointers or std::functions and call them at a later time. I have been searching and experimenting with lua functions (through Sol3) like so:

```
std::function<vec3(float, float, float,vec3)> saved_script = lua_["Idle"]["animate"];

or

vec3 (* Script)(float, float, float, vec3) saved_script = lua["Idle"]["animate"];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That works.

```lua
function InitScript(str)
  return true
end
```

```cpp
using func_t = std::function<bool(std::string)>;
func_t func = m_state.get<func_t>("InitScript"); // sol::state m_state;
bool result = func("some string"); // true
```